# Split url based on environment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have the below urls based on environment separated by hyphen.

1. www-dev.someurl.com  for dev environment
2. www-qa.someurl.com   for qa  environment
3. www.someurl.com      for production, no environment prefix

In one my code snippets i want to dynamically build the above url
based on environment by reading from url (either using $location.host() or window.location.hostname)

can anyone suggest a regex or some code to find out if in the Url there is a envirnment variable (dev/qa)

```
if(contains dev/qa){
    //build url
    } else {
        //build production url
 }
```

Please suggest the best option using regex/code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your earlier comment 'rather than passing qa/dev in regex is there any way where i can get value after hyphen'  , how about this instead of regex :

```
 if((window.location.hostname).indexOf('-')>=0){
     var env= (window.location.hostname).split('-')[1];
     // possible output of env : dev.someurl.com,qa.someurl.com
    }
    else{
    //prod
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression `/www\.(?=(dev|qa))/`

This expression means that;

1. From `www.` value start matching
2. `(?=` Look ahead and see if the word `dev` or `qa` exists
3. if it does then capture `(dev|da)` the word `dev` and `da` value.

The word can be accessed by the 1st index of the matcher.

**Example:**

```js
var urls = [
  "www.qa.someurl.com",
  "www.dev.someurl.com",
  "www.someurl.com"
];

urls.forEach(url=> {
  var qaDevEnv = /www\.(?=(dev|qa))/.exec(url);
  if (qaDevEnv) {
    //build production url
    console.log("URL: ( " + url + " ) is " + qaDevEnv[1] + " environment.");
  } else {
    //build url
    console.log("URL: ( " + url + " ) is a production environment.");
  }
});
```

Comment: rather than passing qa/dev in regex is there any way where i can get value after hyphen, if somevalue is there after hyphen then it means some environment is there, otherwise i can treat as production,  I have to dynamically read this from browser url

Comment: @user804401 - I have updated my solution to do a match and capture the QA or DEV value. let me know if you still have issues

Answer (score 0):

You can build this regex:

```
var regex = /www-(qa|dev)/;
if(regex.test(domain){ ... }
```

Comment: rather than passing qa/dev in regex is there any way where i can get value after hyphen, if somevalue is there after hyphen then it means some environment is there, otherwise i can treat as production,  I have to dynamically read this from browser url

Answer (score 0):

Since the question specifies `www-dev` and not `www.dev`.
We also don't need to use a more complicated look ahead.

```
if( /www-(dev|qa)\./.exec( url ) ) {
  // build url
} else {
  // build production url
}
```

This will also return the value that was matched.

```
/www-(dev|qa)\./.exec( "www-dev.someurl.com" )
["www-dev.", "dev"]

/www-(dev|qa)\./.exec( "www-qa.someurl.com" )
["www-qa.", "qa"]

/www-(dev|qa)\./.exec( "www.someurl.com" )
null
```

Try it out:
https://regex101.com/r/zH7vB0/1

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

Where I don't care what kind of build I am giving manually. everything will be automated.

```
function getDeploymentType(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/(?:-)([^\.]*)/);
    return matches? matches[1]: "prod";
}


build(getDeploymentType(window.location.hostname)); // can return "dev", "qa" or "prod"
```

And in build function the code might look like this:

```
function build(deployType) {
    var deploys = {
        "dev" : {},
        "qa"  : {},
        "prod": {}
    }

    runDeploy(deploys[deployType]);
}
```